# How to run pl/sql statements in Control M for database job/task(execution type :- Embedded Query)

Tags: control-m

I have pl/sql statement something like mentioned below, which executes successfully in oracle sql developer but same when am trying to execute through control M database task (execution type :- Embedded Query) am getting error "Invalid SQL statements"

SQL statements :-

TRUNCATE TABLE TEST;
COMMIT;

EXECUTE USP_LOADTESTTables;
COMMIT;

Answer (score 1):

create a query file named plsql_query.ql then use it to execute from controlM as command line job.
Sqlcmd -E -server\instance_name -Q "EXEC plsql_query.ql"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and explain why and how your solution works.

Comment: This is commandline script for running sqlcmd like plsql, mentioned script has -E for trusted entity or server and -Q is sql script as a text file.